# Netbeans on Mac crashes at Startup when adding plugins

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, plugins, permissions

Every time I add something to my Netbeans it crashes when starting it without `sudo`. For example, when I try to add a Plugin or also when configuring JavaFX, it crashes when closing Netbeans and clicking the icon in the dock again.

Here is some of the messages.log file:

```
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-01-02 13:35:28.797
!MESSAGE Error reading configuration: Permission denied
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.base/java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.initializeInstanceFile(StorageManager.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.open(StorageManager.java:708)
...
```

When running Netbeans by using `sudo /Applications/NetBeans/Apache\ NetBeans\ 12.2.app/Contents/MacOS/netbeans` in the terminal everything works just fine, but in my opinion, this isn't the way it should work.

So does anybody know how to add Plugins,.. and also run the program by clicking the icon?

Comment: Consider the zip distribution and never use sudo

Comment: How does the zip distribution work? I downloaded the zip and dezipped it. And now?

Comment: Look in the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

As the `Permission denied` error suggests, this is most likely due to the permissions - confirm that the user that is trying to launch the application has Read/Write permissions for the `/Applications/NetBeans/Apache\ NetBeans\ 12.2.app/Contents/MacOS/netbeans` folder.

Comment: ´netbeans´ is a symbolic link and both, the link and also the actual file, have all permissions (chmod 777).